# Vim for PHP development: PHP document, manual, completion for builtin function

Tags: php, vim

I have configured my vim to work with PHP, but there's some problems I could not resolve after searching on Google:

- First, about PHP Documentor, I have found php-doc vim plugins, but I could not use it in my code, it just shows me a doc block without anything.

Example:

```
public function set($key, $value)
{
}
```

when I tried to run php-doc (through my configured hotkey: c-p)

```
/**
 *
 **/
public function set($key, $value)
{
}
```

I expected some thing like this:

```
/**
 * 
 * 
 * @param unknown Some thing about parameter 
 * @param unknown Some thing about parameter 
 * @return void
 **/
public function set($key, $value)
{
}
```

- Second, I generated some tags (using ctags) for developing Zend Framework with vim, but after that I don't have any completion for php builtin function (use omni with phpcomplete vim plugins,: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3171 I have changed my syntax to 5.3 used PHP syntax (php.vim: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2874)
- Third, I want my vim php have suggestion for a buitin function or a function with document, when I type a function, it could have a suggestion for the which parameter needs to supplied, what do the functions act? Like this in python: http://blog.dispatched.ch/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/omnicompletion.png

How could I configured vim to fulfill these needs, anyone could help me?

Comment: Edited in real links for you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unless you suspect that all of your issues are related and can be solved by the same answer, it's better to ask them as separate questions; that makes it easier to judge the answers later on.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for an IDE.

Comment: It should be possible to use vim as an IDE

Comment: It *should* be, but unfortunately, support for interpreted languages in vim (and ctags) is atrociously lacking.

Answer (score 0):

- (1) I have not looked at the vim-doc plugins, but for proof of concept, see the `ClassHeader` function and autocommands in foo.vim:  http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=72
- (2, 3)  I get completion for built-in functions and for anything found in a tags file using the syntax and ftplugin files that come with the standard distribution.  Even though I am still using vim 7.3, my syntax file is more recent than the one you mention.  If there is more than one match, then the function signature is shown in a preview window; do you want more than that for a suggestion?  See, for example, the screenshot at https://drupal.org/project/vimrc .